# Xcode 6.1 crashing when running the project

Tags: crash, xcode6

I searched StackOverflow and it doesn't look like many people are having this problem, but for me, this happens very, very frequently. Maybe not every time, but perhaps every other time.

Once I try to build and run the app, Xcode crashes, and in a strange way: it just disappears with no error messages, no suggestion to report the problem, nothing at all. This happened with Xcode 6.0 as well. It doesn't matter whether I am running the app on a device or on an emulator.

To prevent the crash, I need to Product > Clean. If I do this clean each time before running the app, crashes do not happen, but once I forget to do that, Xcode can crash any moment.

I don't think I ever had this crash with an old project, but it keeps happening with the project that I started in Xcode 6.0.

Because of that, iOS development is becoming for me quite a painful exercise, similar to pre-Android-Studio Android development.

Is it just my problem, or maybe someone else is having it? Maybe someone has a solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just started running into the same issue and found a workaround for it. Found it to be an issue with building when Xcode is full screen. Seems silly, but so far exiting full screen mode has worked for me. I've been able to re-introduce the issue after building full screen a few times, and then instantly fix it again by exiting full screen.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes sense indeed: I tend to work full screen. I wonder if there is a way to notify Apple about this issue.

Comment: Woah! Great solution. I never would have thought of not using it in fullscreen. It definitely works for me.

Answer (score 11):

Yeah, it's not that the app is crashing, it's just that the click is triggering the red close window button behind the red button (yeah, seriously).  You'll notice, Xcode is still open, it's just that the window has closed.  You might also notice that sometimes when you click "stop" in full screen mode, it switches to non full screen.  Again, the tap is passing through the run/stop buttons to the underlying window controls.

So dumb.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me positioning the 'click' so I don't trigger the underlying button. Really Apple, what were you thinking?

Comment: That's quite amazing, especially since this problem already existed in Xcode 6.0 on Yosemite. How could they have NOT fixed that in 6.1?

Answer (score 7):

I solved it using 'cmd + R' instead of clicking the run button